# Remove the expression from middle of a url

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have following image url:

```
https://img.com/woo/image/u/f_auto,q_auto/w_350/v1619377072/Products/dada/Products/dada/IMG_47473065_IDW_IMAGE_bf30ac4dbbd308c8b0248b954a58a731a5b413b0f6782b834c781d0da621d727_HR.jpg
```

Here url containing by default resolution i.e. `w_350` in it. I want to remove this resolution from this image url.

Final output of image url should be like this :

```
https://img.com/woo/image/u/f_auto,q_auto/v1619377072/Products/dada/Products/dada/IMG_47473065_IDW_IMAGE_bf30ac4dbbd308c8b0248b954a58a731a5b413b0f6782b834c781d0da621d727_HR.jpg
```

How can I do this?

Is there anything better than this?

```
re.sub(r"w_\d\d\d/", "", url)
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to know for sure, but I guess maybe something like this will work you: `'/'.join([part for part in s.split('/') if not any(part.startswith(prefix) for prefix in ('w_', 'l_'))])`

Answer (score 1):

I just tested and this worked

```
import re
pattern = "([a-z]_[0-9]{3}\/)"
original_string = "https://img.com/woo/image/u/f_auto,q_auto/w_350/v1619377072/Products/f6782b834c781d0da621d727_HR.jpg"
changed = re.sub(pattern, "", original_string)
#output
```

should give you this value

```
"https://img.com/woo/image/u/f_auto,q_auto/v1619377072/Products/f6782b834c781d0da621d727_HR.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach: If you are sure the pattern will only contain digits `0-9` it's always better to use `[0-9]` rather than `\d`, as from the documentation:

> `\d` Matches any Unicode decimal digit (that is, any character in
> Unicode character category [Nd]). This includes [0-9], and also many
> other digit characters. If the ASCII flag is used only [0-9] is
> matched.

Using `[0-9]` will reduce the computation as only the digit `0-9` will be matched and not all the Unicode characters.

```
import re
url = 'https://img.com/woo/image/u/f_auto,q_auto/w_350/v1619377072/Products/dada/Products/dada/IMG_47473065_IDW_IMAGE_bf30ac4dbbd308c8b0248b954a58a731a5b413b0f6782b834c781d0da621d727_HR.jpg'

url = re.sub(r'[a-z]_[0-9]{3}/', '', url)
print (url)
```

Output:

```
https://img.com/woo/image/u/f_auto,q_auto/v1619377072/Products/dada/Products/dada/IMG_47473065_IDW_IMAGE_bf30ac4dbbd308c8b0248b954a58a731a5b413b0f6782b834c781d0da621d727_HR.jpg
```